# Android espresso not clicking smaller buttons

Tags: android, automated-tests, android-espresso

I'm just starting to write tests for android, and I'm worried I'm doing something wrong. Here is my code for the test:

```
@Rule
public IntentsTestRule<LoginActivity> mActivityRule = new IntentsTestRule<>(LoginActivity.class, true);

@Test
public void forgotPassDialog() throws Exception {
    onView(withId(R.id.logForgotPassTxt))
            .perform(ViewActions.click());
    getInstrumentation().waitForIdleSync();
    onView(withText(R.string.forgotPassDialogTitle)).check(matches(isDisplayed()));
}
```

It clicks a button, and then checks to see if the proper dialog is popping up. Here's the weird part:

It works fine as long as android:minHeight on the button is set to 22dp or higher. 21dp or lower, and the test fails. I've tried setting the style of the button instead of manually doing minHeight, same problem. It looks like the dialog doesn't pop up at all, but if I test myself inside the app, it works fine.

Is there any reason that the height of the button should matter?

Here is the failed stack trace:

```
android.support.test.espresso.NoMatchingViewException: No views in hierarchy found matching: with string from resource id: <2131165243>[forgotPassDialogTitle] value: Reset Password
at dalvik.system.VMStack.getThreadStackTrace(Native Method)
at java.lang.Thread.getStackTrace(Thread.java:1567)
at android.support.test.espresso.base.DefaultFailureHandler.getUserFriendlyError(DefaultFailureHandler.java:92)
at android.support.test.espresso.base.DefaultFailureHandler.handle(DefaultFailureHandler.java:56)
at android.support.test.espresso.ViewInteraction.runSynchronouslyOnUiThread(ViewInteraction.java:184)
at android.support.test.espresso.ViewInteraction.check(ViewInteraction.java:158)
at com.esborders.webphysician.LoginActivityTest.forgotPassDialog(LoginActivityTest.java:98)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
at android.support.test.internal.statement.UiThreadStatement.evaluate(UiThreadStatement.java:55)
at android.support.test.rule.ActivityTestRule$ActivityStatement.evaluate(ActivityTestRule.java:270)
at org.junit.rules.RunRules.evaluate(RunRules.java:20)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:128)
at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:27)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:115)
at android.support.test.internal.runner.TestExecutor.execute(TestExecutor.java:59)
at android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner.onStart(AndroidJUnitRunner.java:262)
at android.app.Instrumentation$InstrumentationThread.run(Instrumentation.java:1967)
```

Comment: "test fails" as in crash?

Comment: it's a failed test, not a crash exactly. I'll put the stack trace in the question

Comment: can you share the exact layout snippet from that button?

Comment: did you find a solution to your problem? I am having the same one.